# Why is AEON wallet not working on Bittrex?

Tags: development, aeon, exchange, bittrex

Withdrawals and deposits for AEON are disabled on Bittrex, while trading works. Is there actual maintenance going on? Are developers in contact with Bittrex?
When do you expect this problem to be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

There were some large reorgs/forks in June 2017, like on the order of 50 or 100 blocks, the cause of which was not clear. Prior to that there was a bug that required a chain rollback, which resulted in delisting from cryptopia exchange. After these incidents the maintainer of aeon GitHub repo, smooth, requested bittrex to take the wallet offline until aeon could be updated to a more recent monero codebase. That process still hasn't been completed, so the wallet is still offline.

Comment: Why is it taking so long? Do you have any recent information how is this process of updating the codebase going? I really need to know when is it expected to be finished and AEON wallet working again on Bittrex.
I am getting worried because I don't understand why is some casual updating taking few weeks and still no official announcments from AEON nor from Bittrex. Can you guarantee that they are working on it and it WILL be fixed soon?